# How to insert values from two tables into one in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have 3 non-empty tables:

| Movie |
| --- |
| movie_id |
| movie_name |

| Actor |
| --- |
| actor_id |
| last_name |
| first_name |

And the bridge table:

| Movie_actor |
| --- |
| movie_id |
| actor_id |

I have added 3 new movies into 'movies', and 6 new actors to 'actor', that play in these movies (2 per each).

I need to insert my updates into the bridge table 'movie_actor'.

The logic is:

for movie1 add actors A, B,

for movie2 add actors C, D

for movie3 add actors E, F

The problem is that I don't want to write this query 3 times for each movie:

```sql
INSERT INTO movie_actor (actor.actor_id, movie.movie_id) 

SELECT actor.actor_id, movie.movie_id
FROM actor, movie
WHERE actor_id IN (201, 202)
AND film_id = 1;
```

Is there any other way to write it all into one query? I believe it must be.
thank you in advance!

Comment: You might try to add additional actor-film-combo-conditions with an ```OR```. So after the ```WHERE``` your statement could be like ```(actor_id IN (1, 2) AND film_id = 1) OR (actor_id IN (3, 4) AND film_id = 2) OR (actor_id IN (5, 6) AND film_id = 3)```.

Comment: If you want to add six new relations between `movie` and `actor`, you have to insert six rows into the junction table. How else should the database know which rows are related?

Comment: `INSERT INTO movie_actor (actor.actor_id, movie.movie_id)` has to be `INSERT INTO movie_actor (actor_id, movie_id)`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to run your query once and insert 6 rows of (`movie_id`, `actor_id`) into `movie_actor` bridge table by select data out of the cartesian product of `movie` and `actor` based on `movie_id` and `actor_id` given.

By comparing each row returned from the Cartesian product with given pairs of (`movie_id`, `actor_id`) as below in one single `insert...select...`:

```sql
insert into movie_actor
 select movie_id, actor_id
  from actor, movie
 where array[(movie_id, actor_id)] <@ array[(1,201), (1,202), (2,301), (2,302), (3, 401), (3,402)];
```

Of course, the traditional `insert` always work for less but it's not the way you like it:

```sql
insert into movie_actor
values
(1,201), (1,202), (2,301), (2,302), (3, 401), (3,402);
```